# No interactive elements in screenshot

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, screenshot

**I'm doing screenshot with this code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36')
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap,service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any','--web-security=false']) 
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.get("https://app.wisemapping.com/c/maps/579829/public")
driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')
driver.quit()
```

And what i get is only this:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGpIL.png)

If you go to the [website](https://app.wisemapping.com/c/maps/579829/public) where i doing that, you can see there is mindmap.
I don't know what the problem, i tried chromedriver and everything is same, however, on other websites everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a webdriver wait so that the element appear on screen and than take screenshot

these are imports which you need

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

add this line before taking screenshot

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#workspace > g:nth-child(3) > rect:nth-child(2)")))
```

Post that you will see correct screenshot
[image]

Comment: Error, i tried more time, still doesn't work.
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\", line 13, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#workspace > g:nth-child(3) > rect:nth-child(2)")))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Screenshot: available via screen`

Comment: can you try code with Chromedriver, see if it works , in the mean time i am looking for PhantomJS issue

Comment: Ok, i tried Chromedriver, now it's works, for some reason i guess PhantomJS not working properly for that website.

Comment: I am also seeing error when using PhantomJS, i will update you when find any solution for it

Answer (score 1):

Its a timing issue. The screen shot is taken before the elements are loaded and become visible. Use explicit wait to wait for them

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver.get("https://app.wisemapping.com/c/maps/579829/public")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#workspaceContainer > svg > [preserveAspectRatio]")))

driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')
```